# SeekBar does not work

Tags: android, eclipse

I have the below code refering to a Seekbar for increase-decrease my volume

```
private void initControls(){
    try
    {
        volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));   


        volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
            {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        progress, 0);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This refers to a seekbar. It does not work, I mean it does not increase my volume when I move it

Comment: Do you call `isVolumeFixed()` anywhere to check whether `setStreamVolume()` will work?

Comment: Is the onProgressChanged method ever called?

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar problem with the SeekBar once. The onProgressChanged method was never called and I never figured out why. Instead I used the onStopTrackingTouch method like this:

```
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
  this.foo = seekBar.getProgress();
}
```